# [SQL ]How to sum the value in some parts of column

Tags: sql

I am practicing SQL and here is my exercise(Table 1)
[Table 1: The origin table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xgdp.png)
My goal is to have the sum of income when Month is between 1 and 3. If Month=4, the income s`enter code here`hould not be added in.

|M_Id |  Year |  Month  | CompanyID  |  CustomerID  |    MonthIncome |

|1    | 110   |    1    |     T012   |       C001   |         30000  |

|2    | 110   |    2    |     T012   |       C001   |         60000  |

|3    | 110   |    3    |     T012   |       C001   |         60000  |

|4    | 110   |    4    |     T012   |       C001   |        100000  |

|5    | 110   |    1    |     A012   |       A001   |         10000  |

|6    | 110   |    1    |     A012   |       A001   |         50000  |

I tried some SQL:
select companyID, customerID, Year, Sum(MonthIncome) as Total
from[dbo].[Money]
group by year,companyID, customerID

and the table result look like this:
[Table 2. using sum, group by , and the table become](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1zpG.png)

| Year |  CompanyID  |  CustomerID   |   MonthIncome|

| 110  |       A012  |      A001     |         60000|

| 110  |       T012  |      C001     |        250000|

The table style is what I want, but the sum(Income) is not right because it had included month=4.
I tried to change my sql to
select companyID, customerID, Year, Sum(MonthIncome) as Total
from[dbo].[Money]
group by year,companyID, customerID
having month between 1 and 3

but the system as me to put the month into group by, and then table style is not what I want.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: don't put your problems and details in a link, and just the table format in the question. put the details in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the months that are not in the range 1 to 3 using WHERE then do the grouping:

```
SELECT year, companyID, customerID, Sum(MonthIncome) AS Total 
FROM [dbo].[Money] 
WHERE month BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY year, companyID, customerID;
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought group by can not be used after where and never try, thank you !